# Remove a part of string from each element of an array in php

Tags: php

I have a array

```
["item1","item2","item3"]
```

I want to get an array of ["1","2","3"]

how to get that in php

Comment: 1) Have you tried something to achieve this? 2) What is the pattern behind this?

Comment: no, this is an array I want only the number of array from that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this

```
$arr = ["item1","item2","item3"];

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
    // replace "item" with ""
    $arr[$i] = str_replace("item","",$arr[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$given_array = ["item1","item2","item3"];
$new_array = array();
foreach ($given_array as $arr) {
    $new_array[] = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $arr), 10);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Simply use

```
$res = str_replace('item', '', $array);
```

**Output 
  $res**

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
)
```

2) Using [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$array = array_map(
  function($str) {
    return str_replace('item', '', $str);
  },
  $array
);
```